# Как создать связь между таблицами в Yii 1.1?

Tags: php, база-данных, yii

Есть у  меня три таблицы. Нужно реализовать между ними связь через внешний ключ и как то соединить в Yii 1.1, чтобы можно было выводить сначала данные с таблицы Property, а потом Parameters [image: **Структура базы данных**]

Answer (score 1):

Оперируйте не таблицами, а моделями ActiveRecord. 
[Здесь](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.arr) можете прочитать про связи и как их устанавливать между AR. Для того чтобы заполнять сначала Property не валидируйте внешний ключ у зависимой модели (на наличие)